# i want to check words against matrix. but i am not able to identify all the words in all 8 directions in matrix

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix

I ahve a matrix of characters with characters spread in a way that they make a meaningful word.
also i have an array of words. These are the words whose characters are spread in the matrix along with there x,y starting positions and x,y ending positions. Now i want to extract an array of strings made by adding all the characters on the given positions. here is my code:

```
function findWords(words, matrix) {
  const foundWords = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    const word = words[i].word;
    const startX = words[i].startX;
    const startY = words[i].startY;
    const endX = words[i].endX;
    const endY = words[i].endY;

    let wordIndex = 0;
    let wordFound = true;

    if (startX === endX) {
      // Horizontal (Left to Right)
      if (startY < endY) {
        for (let y = startY; y <= endY; y++) {
          if (matrix[startX][y] !== word[wordIndex]) {
            wordFound = false;
            break;
          }
          wordIndex++;
        }
      }
      // Horizontal (Right to Left)
      else {
        for (let y = endY; y <= startY; y++) {
          if (matrix[startX][y] !== word[wordIndex]) {
            wordFound = false;
            break;
          }
          wordIndex++;
        }
      }
    } else if (startY === endY) {
      // Vertical (Top to Bottom)
      if (startX < endX) {
        for (let x = startX; x <= endX; x++) {
          if (matrix[x][startY] !== word[wordIndex]) {
            wordFound = false;
            break;
          }
          wordIndex++;
        }
      }
      // Vertical (Bottom to Top)
      else {
        for (let x = endX; x <= startX; x++) {
          if (matrix[x][startY] !== word[wordIndex]) {
            wordFound = false;
            break;
          }
          wordIndex++;
        }
      }
    } else if (startX < endX) {
      // diagonal (top-left to bottom-right) word
      for (let x = startX, y = startY; x <= endX; x++, y++) {
        if (matrix[x][y] !== word[wordIndex]) {
          wordFound = false;
          break;
        }
        wordIndex++;
      }
    } else {
      // diagonal (bottom-left to top-right) word
      for (let x = startX, y = startY; x >= endX; x--, y--) {
        if (matrix[x][y] !== word[wordIndex]) {
          wordFound = false;
          break;
        }
        wordIndex++;
      }
    }

    if (wordFound) {
      foundWords.push(word);
    } else {
      wordFound = true;
      wordIndex = 0;

      // Check diagonally (bottom-right to top-left)
      for (let x = endX, y = endY; x >= startX; x--, y--) {
        if (matrix[x][y] !== word[wordIndex]) {
          wordFound = false;
          break;
        }
        wordIndex++;
      }

      if (wordFound) {
        foundWords.push(word);
      } else {
        wordFound = true;
        wordIndex = 0;

        // Check diagonally (top-right to bottom-left)
        for (let x = startX, y = endY; x <= endX; x++, y--) {
          if (matrix[x][y] !== word[wordIndex]) {
            wordFound = false;
            break;
          }
          wordIndex++;
        }

        if (wordFound) {
          foundWords.push(word);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return foundWords;
}

const solve = [
  { word: "butter", startX: 3, startY: 6, endX: 3, endY: 1 },
  { word: "chicken", startX: 8, startY: 2, endX: 2, endY: 2 },
  { word: "coconut", startX: 9, startY: 10, endX: 3, endY: 4 },
  { word: "gremilins", startX: 1, startY: 0, endX: 9, endY: 8 },
  { word: "ham", startX: 7, startY: 2, endX: 5, endY: 0 },
  { word: "iceland", startX: 10, startY: 1, endX: 4, endY: 1 },
  { word: "italy", startX: 6, startY: 2, endX: 6, endY: 6 },
  { word: "korea", startX: 2, startY: 8, endX: 6, endY: 4 },
  { word: "portugal", startX: 9, startY: 9, endX: 2, endY: 9 },
  { word: "psycho", startX: 10, startY: 8, endX: 5, endY: 8 },
  { word: "rabbit", startX: 10, startY: 5, endX: 10, endY: 0 },
  { word: "sandwich", startX: 3, startY: 10, endX: 10, endY: 10 },
  { word: "serbia", startX: 9, startY: 8, endX: 9, endY: 3 },
  { word: "singapore", startX: 0, startY: 10, endX: 0, endY: 2 },
  { word: "tomato", startX: 3, startY: 0, endX: 8, endY: 0 },
];

const matrix = [
  ["r", "g", "j", "t", "o", "m", "a", "t", "o", "w", "t"],
  ["z", "a", "r", "r", "d", "n", "a", "l", "e", "c", "i"],
  ["e", "m", "n", "e", "k", "c", "i", "h", "c", "f", "b"],
  ["r", "c", "t", "t", "m", "a", "t", "v", "a", "a", "b"],
  ["o", "z", "q", "t", "t", "i", "a", "o", "u", "i", "a"],
  ["p", "j", "z", "u", "u", "e", "l", "u", "z", "b", "r"],
  ["a", "o", "e", "b", "r", "n", "y", "i", "z", "r", "g"],
  ["g", "n", "n", "o", "h", "w", "o", "h", "n", "e", "a"],
  ["n", "q", "k", "u", "w", "o", "h", "c", "y", "s", "p"],
  ["i", "j", "l", "a", "g", "u", "t", "r", "o", "p", "n"],
  ["s", "h", "y", "s", "a", "n", "d", "w", "i", "c", "h"],
];

console.log(findWords(solve, matrix));
```

this is the output that i am getting:

```
[ 'chicken', 'coconut', 'ham', 'iceland', 'portugal', 'psycho' ]
```

but i want all the words found from this array.

```
const solve = [
      { word: "butter", startX: 3, startY: 6, endX: 3, endY: 1 },
      { word: "chicken", startX: 8, startY: 2, endX: 2, endY: 2 },
      { word: "coconut", startX: 9, startY: 10, endX: 3, endY: 4 },
      { word: "gremilins", startX: 1, startY: 0, endX: 9, endY: 8 },
      { word: "ham", startX: 7, startY: 2, endX: 5, endY: 0 },
      { word: "iceland", startX: 10, startY: 1, endX: 4, endY: 1 },
      { word: "italy", startX: 6, startY: 2, endX: 6, endY: 6 },
      { word: "korea", startX: 2, startY: 8, endX: 6, endY: 4 },
      { word: "portugal", startX: 9, startY: 9, endX: 2, endY: 9 },
      { word: "psycho", startX: 10, startY: 8, endX: 5, endY: 8 },
      { word: "rabbit", startX: 10, startY: 5, endX: 10, endY: 0 },
      { word: "sandwich", startX: 3, startY: 10, endX: 10, endY: 10 },
      { word: "serbia", startX: 9, startY: 8, endX: 9, endY: 3 },
      { word: "singapore", startX: 0, startY: 10, endX: 0, endY: 2 },
      { word: "tomato", startX: 3, startY: 0, endX: 8, endY: 0 },
    ];
```

and all these words are present in the above matrix.

Comment: _"along with there x,y starting positions and x,y ending positions"_ - so that means you are not looking for those words written _anywhere_ inside the matrix, going in _any_ arbitrary direction - but only those, that inside the matrix actually start exactly at the given startX and startY, and end at the endX / endY positions? So one could say, you are not "searching" for those words, but rather just verifying whether an already given "solution" is actually correct - yes?

Comment: yes exactly. I am only extracting words from the matrix in the given positions by the solved array.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a bug in your code. Not sure where. Here's how I'd start.

```js
function extractWord(matrix, startX, startY, endX, endY) {
    const xDir = Math.sign(endX - startX); // 1, -1, or 0
    const yDir = Math.sign(endY - startY);
    let word = '';
    for (let x = startX, y = startY;
         (xDir === 1 ? x <= endX : x >= endX) &&
         (yDir === 1 ? y <= endY : y >= endY);
         x += xDir, y += yDir
    ) {
        word += matrix[y][x];
    }
    return word;
}

const matrix = [["r", "g", "j", "t", "o", "m", "a", "t", "o", "w", "t"],["z", "a", "r", "r", "d", "n", "a", "l", "e", "c", "i"],["e", "m", "n", "e", "k", "c", "i", "h", "c", "f", "b"],["r", "c", "t", "t", "m", "a", "t", "v", "a", "a", "b"],["o", "z", "q", "t", "t", "i", "a", "o", "u", "i", "a"],["p", "j", "z", "u", "u", "e", "l", "u", "z", "b", "r"],["a", "o", "e", "b", "r", "n", "y", "i", "z", "r", "g"],["g", "n", "n", "o", "h", "w", "o", "h", "n", "e", "a"],["n", "q", "k", "u", "w", "o", "h", "c", "y", "s", "p"],["i", "j", "l", "a", "g", "u", "t", "r", "o", "p", "n"],["s", "h", "y", "s", "a", "n", "d", "w", "i", "c", "h"]];
const solve = [{ word: "butter", startX: 3, startY: 6, endX: 3, endY: 1 },{ word: "chicken", startX: 8, startY: 2, endX: 2, endY: 2 },{ word: "coconut", startX: 9, startY: 10, endX: 3, endY: 4 },{ word: "gremilins", startX: 1, startY: 0, endX: 9, endY: 8 },{ word: "ham", startX: 7, startY: 2, endX: 5, endY: 0 },{ word: "iceland", startX: 10, startY: 1, endX: 4, endY: 1 },{ word: "italy", startX: 6, startY: 2, endX: 6, endY: 6 },{ word: "korea", startX: 2, startY: 8, endX: 6, endY: 4 },{ word: "portugal", startX: 9, startY: 9, endX: 2, endY: 9 },{ word: "psycho", startX: 10, startY: 8, endX: 5, endY: 8 },{ word: "rabbit", startX: 10, startY: 5, endX: 10, endY: 0 },{ word: "sandwich", startX: 3, startY: 10, endX: 10, endY: 10 },{ word: "serbia", startX: 9, startY: 8, endX: 9, endY: 3 },{ word: "singapore", startX: 0, startY: 10, endX: 0, endY: 2 },{ word: "tomato", startX: 3, startY: 0, endX: 8, endY: 0 }];

console.log(solve.map(s => extractWord(matrix, s.startX, s.startY, s.endX, s.endY)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating things a bit. All you need is the start point and the direction, then horizontal, vertical, diagonal become all the same.

```js
function findWords(words, matrix) {
  return words.filter(({ word, startX, startY, endX, endY }) => {
    const vx = Math.sign(endX - startX);
    const vy = Math.sign(endY - startY);

    return [...word].every((char, i) => char === matrix[startY + i * vy][startX + i * vx]);
  }).map(elm => elm.word);
}

const solve = [
  { word: "butter", startX: 3, startY: 6, endX: 3, endY: 1 },
  { word: "chicken", startX: 8, startY: 2, endX: 2, endY: 2 },
  { word: "coconut", startX: 9, startY: 10, endX: 3, endY: 4 },
  { word: "gremilins", startX: 1, startY: 0, endX: 9, endY: 8 },
  { word: "ham", startX: 7, startY: 2, endX: 5, endY: 0 },
  { word: "iceland", startX: 10, startY: 1, endX: 4, endY: 1 },
  { word: "italy", startX: 6, startY: 2, endX: 6, endY: 6 },
  { word: "korea", startX: 2, startY: 8, endX: 6, endY: 4 },
  { word: "portugal", startX: 9, startY: 9, endX: 2, endY: 9 },
  { word: "psycho", startX: 10, startY: 8, endX: 5, endY: 8 },
  { word: "rabbit", startX: 10, startY: 5, endX: 10, endY: 0 },
  { word: "sandwich", startX: 3, startY: 10, endX: 10, endY: 10 },
  { word: "serbia", startX: 9, startY: 8, endX: 9, endY: 3 },
  { word: "singapore", startX: 0, startY: 10, endX: 0, endY: 2 },
  { word: "tomato", startX: 3, startY: 0, endX: 8, endY: 0 },
];

const matrix = [
  ["r", "g", "j", "t", "o", "m", "a", "t", "o", "w", "t"],
  ["z", "a", "r", "r", "d", "n", "a", "l", "e", "c", "i"],
  ["e", "m", "n", "e", "k", "c", "i", "h", "c", "f", "b"],
  ["r", "c", "t", "t", "m", "a", "t", "v", "a", "a", "b"],
  ["o", "z", "q", "t", "t", "i", "a", "o", "u", "i", "a"],
  ["p", "j", "z", "u", "u", "e", "l", "u", "z", "b", "r"],
  ["a", "o", "e", "b", "r", "n", "y", "i", "z", "r", "g"],
  ["g", "n", "n", "o", "h", "w", "o", "h", "n", "e", "a"],
  ["n", "q", "k", "u", "w", "o", "h", "c", "y", "s", "p"],
  ["i", "j", "l", "a", "g", "u", "t", "r", "o", "p", "n"],
  ["s", "h", "y", "s", "a", "n", "d", "w", "i", "c", "h"],
];

console.log(findWords(solve, matrix));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0; max-height:100%!important}
```

I assume that the data in `solve` is at least in itself consistent. Or do we need to check if for example endX-startX is consisitent with the words length
or that the points are consisitent with the 8 directions and don't do something like 2 to the right, 8 down while the word has only 5 letters.